# Deployment with Big_Mod_Exp Failure

Tags: solana-program

I'm encountering a deployment issue with program due to a failure related to Big_Mod_Exp. When I comment it out, the program deploys successfully, but when it's included, deployment fails. Could you advise on how to resolve this issue?

```
use crate::*;

use std::cmp::Ordering;
use num::{BigUint, FromPrimitive};

const EULERS_CRITERION_POWER: &[u8; 32] = &[127, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 127, 255, 254, 23];
const FIELD_SIZE: &[u8; 32] = &[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 254, 255, 255, 252, 47];
const SUITE: u8 = 0x03;

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(params: RequestRandomWordsParams)] // rpc parameters hint
pub struct RequestRandomWords<'info> {
    /// CHECK
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = consumer,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<RequestState>(),
        seeds = [REQUEST, &params.pre_seed],
        bump,
    )]
    pub request: Account<'info, RequestState>,

    /// CHECK
    #[account(
        mut,
        constraint = consumer_state.allowed == 1 @ VrfError::NotConsumer,
        seeds = [CONSUMER, consumer.key().as_ref()],
        bump = consumer_state.bump,
    )]
    pub consumer_state: Account<'info, ConsumerState>,

    /// CHECK House permit
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub consumer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(address = solana_program::system_program::ID)]
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Clone, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct RequestRandomWordsParams {
    pub num_words: u8,
    pub pre_seed: [u8; 32],
}

impl RequestRandomWords<'_> {
    pub fn actuate(ctx: Context<Self>, params: &RequestRandomWordsParams) -> anchor_lang::Result<()> {
        let timestamp = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp;

        let mut h = hash_to_curve(&VRF_PUB_KEY, &params.pre_seed);

        let bme = &big_mod_exp(&h, &[SUITE], FIELD_SIZE);
        let y: &BigUint = &BigUint::from_bytes_be(bme);

        let bme2 = &big_mod_exp(&y.to_bytes_be(), EULERS_CRITERION_POWER, FIELD_SIZE);
        let r = BigUint::from_bytes_be(bme2);
        
        if BigUint::from_u8(1).unwrap().cmp(&r) != Ordering::Equal {
            h = field_hash(&h);
        }

        let hash: [u8; 32] = to_array(h);

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `big_mod_exp` syscall is currently disabled on all networks.

If your program uses a syscall that is not enabled on a network, the loader will forbid deployment of that program.

This is to avoid a potential segfault if your program executes and attempts to use the syscall.

So for now, you'll need to remove the syscall.